# Place notification beneath the divider android java

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I am busy with notifications, and I was wondering how I could archieve such thing as in the image below. I tried setting it as `ongoing`, but it didn't quite archieve the functionality I would like it to be.

How can I place my notification beneath that divider? (So above or under `USB for charging`)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your notification to [PRIORITY_MIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_MIN):

```
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
```